# seaborn or matplotlib bar plot multiple dataframes side by side

Tags: matplotlib, plot, jupyter-notebook, seaborn

Using matplotlib I was trying to put bar plots next to each other. This is pretty common and I've gone through a bunch of stackoverflow pages but something still isn't right.

df1

```
    Net Count   date
0   AA  242624806   2018-03-01 00:00:00.000
1   AA  213729127   2018-03-01 00:01:00.000
2   AA  4482234727  2018-03-01 00:02:00.000
3   AA  26042386    2018-03-01 00:03:00.000
4   AA  13444400    2018-03-01 00:04:00.000
```

df2

```
    Net Count   date
0   BB  242806      2018-03-01 00:00:00.000
1   BB  729127      2018-03-01 00:01:00.000
2   BB  85872722    2018-03-01 00:02:00.000
3   BB  26006231    2018-03-01 00:03:00.000
4   BB  123115400   2018-03-01 00:04:00.000
```

df3

```
    Net Count   date
0   CC  452806      2018-03-01 00:00:00.000
1   CC  129127      2018-03-01 00:01:00.000
2   CC  858722      2018-03-01 00:02:00.000
3   CC  26216231    2018-03-01 00:03:00.000
4   CC  33115400    2018-03-01 00:04:00.000
```

Code:

```
x=df['date']  #since the date are the same in both tables I only have 1 x
y=df['count']
y2=d2['count']
y3=d2['count']

plt.figure(figsize=(15,8))
plt.bar(x,y,label="AA")
plt.bar(x,y2,label="BB")
plt.bar(x,y3,label="CC")

plt.title("Count by Networks")
plt.legend(title="Network")
plt.show()
```

Here is how it looks : [image]
But I've tried `align=edge`, `align=center` and playing around with the widths but it is always overlapping.

How would I make this work so that the bars are not stacked so they are side by side?

Like this:
 [image]



**** Updated with Answer *****
Y.Luo this worked for me the best in pandas like this:

```
dateindex=df1['date']

aa=dict(zip(x,df1['count']))
bb=dict(zip(x,df2['count']))
cc=dict(zip(x,df3['count']))
dd=dict(zip(x,df4['count']))
ee=dict(zip(x,df5['count']))


dfbar = pd.DataFrame({'AA': aa, 'BB': bb, 'CC': cc,'DD': dd, 'EE': ee}, index=dateindex)

# Non-stacked bar plot
dfbar.plot.bar(figsize=(16, 6))

plt.title("Count by Networks")
plt.legend(title="Network")
plt.show()
```

Comment: You can merge your data in a single dataframe, one column per original dataframe and plot it with pandas. You can also append all dataframes to create a long form table with another column specifying the category and use seaborn's hue argument. I think there are enough questions on both methods around. If you have a problem implementing them, ask a specific question about that problem.

Comment: Thats the problem theres too many ways @ImportanceOfBeingErnest . Which method do you suggest, still a bit new on all of this. I'd like an example of ^ in matplotlib since I use that most often

Comment: Pandas is easiest. Matplotlib is the most versatile. Are the dates actual dates or strings in your dataframe?

Comment: its a date, generated by date_trunc('minute', log_time). I also saw something about plt.hist

Comment: You know for answering this question I would now need to replicate those dataframes myself. This is really too much work. If you want help, just provide a [mcve] from the beginning.

Comment: actually jus treat it as a string for this purpose it doesnt matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a non-stacked bar plot with matplotlib, you would need to adjust the position for each dataframe yourself like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Example data
n=24
dateindex = pd.date_range(pd.datetime(2018, 1, 1), periods=n)
np.random.seed(1)
aa = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(n), columns=['count'], index=dateindex)
np.random.seed(2)
bb = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(n), columns=['count'], index=dateindex)
np.random.seed(3)
cc = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(n), columns=['count'], index=dateindex)

# Non-stacked bar plot
plt.figure(figsize=(16, 6))
width = 0.25
plt.bar(np.arange(len(aa))-width, aa.values, width, label="AA")
plt.bar(np.arange(len(aa)), bb.values, width, label="BB")
plt.bar(np.arange(len(aa))+width, cc.values, width, label="CC")
plt.xticks(np.arange(len(aa)), dateindex, rotation='vertical')

plt.title("Count by Networks")
plt.legend(title="Network")
plt.show()
```

[image: Non-stacked bar plot with matplotlib]

ImportanceOfBeingErnest is correct. Pandas is the easiest since it does the adjustment for you:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Example data
n=24
dateindex = pd.date_range(pd.datetime(2018, 1, 1), periods=n)
np.random.seed(1)
aa = np.random.randn(n)
np.random.seed(2)
bb = np.random.randn(n)
np.random.seed(3)
cc = np.random.randn(n)
df = pd.DataFrame({'AA': aa, 'BB': bb, 'CC': cc}, index=dateindex)

# Non-stacked bar plot
df.plot.bar(figsize=(16, 6))

plt.title("Count by Networks")
plt.legend(title="Network")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks this is great, I noticed an issue I had was if I had 5 bars instead of 3 I had trouble moving them without the 1st bar overlapping unless I narrowed down the width of the bar. Eventually got it to work by doing this `width = 0.19
plt.bar(np.arange(len(aa))-(width*2),y.values,width, label=“aa”)
plt.bar(np.arange(len(bb))-width,y2.values,width, label=“bb”)
plt.bar(np.arange(len(cc)),y3.values,width, label=“cc”)
plt.bar(np.arange(len(dd))+width,y4,width,label=“dd”)
plt.bar(np.arange(len(ee))+width*2,y4,width,label=“ee”)` is there a better way to adjust? This will work tho thx!

Comment: Tying to use pandas. I think its not working for me because I am trying to make aa = df['count'] , for example `aa=df1[‘count’]
bb=df2[‘count’]
cc=df3[‘count’]
dfbar = pd.DataFrame({'AA': aa, 'BB': bb, 'CC': cc}, index=dateindex)` How do I property get my values into aa/bb/cc correctly with my source data is a column in a dataframe? Thanks

Comment: For your first comment, I'm not really sure what do you mean by "better". If you want to do it automatically, I think the best way is ImportanceOfBeingErnest's suggestion, i.e. use Pandas as you did in the second comment. It saves your time to code an adjustment algorithm yourself. If you want to make it prettier, I don't really know how other than make a wider graph since the space is limitted.

Comment: For your second comment, I would suggest [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html). I cannot put too much code here. But it can be something like `pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], axis=1)` if the index is consistent.

Comment: Got it working by doing this! `aa=dict(zip(x,df1['count']))
bb=dict(zip(x,df2['count']]))
cc=dict(zip(x,df3['count']))
dd=dict(zip(x,df4['count']]))
ee=dict(zip(x,df5['count']))` where x is df['date'] I'll try with pd.co
ncat too thanks!