# Print a bar chart with different dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, charts

As you can see I have three dataframes.

I printed all the information about the values, with:

```
print("Amount of cardids " , df_x['Carid'].nunique())
print("Amount of carnames " , df_x['Carname'].nunique())
print("Amount of models" , df_x['model'].nunique())
```

Now I want to print them in a bar chart.

[image: Bar chat]

As you can see I would like to print all the dataframes in one bar chart, that you can see the amount of the fields.

```
d_1 = {'Carid ': [1, 2, 3], 'Carname': ['Mercedes-Benz', 'Audi', 'BMW'], 'model': ['S-Klasse AMG 63s', 'S6', 'X6 M-Power']}
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d_1)
print(df_1.head())

d_2 = {'Carid ': [1, 2, 4], 'Carname': ['Mercedes-Benz', 'Audi', 'VW'], 'model': ['S-Klasse AMG 63s', 'S6', 'GTI']}
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d_2)
print(df_2.head())

d_3 = {'Carid ': [1, 3, 8], 'Carname': ['Mercedes-Benz', 'VW', 'Opel'], 'model': ['S-Klasse AMG 63s', 'GTD', 'Corsa']}
df_3 = pd.DataFrame(data=d_!)
print(df_3.head())
```

How could I print this bar chart with all three dataframes and call the amounts?

Comment: Take a look here:    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49289189/seaborn-or-matplotlib-bar-plot-multiple-dataframes-side-by-side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using the matplotlib bar function. The code is as follows:

```
carids = [df_1['Carid'].nunique(), df_2['Carid'].nunique(), df_3['Carid'].nunique()]
carname = [df_1['Carname'].nunique(), df_2['Carname'].nunique(), df_3['Carname'].nunique()]
models = [df_1['model'].nunique(), df_2['model'].nunique(), df_3['model'].nunique()]

labels = ["df_1", "df_2", "df_3"]
width = 0.05
x = np.arange(len(labels))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
rects1 = ax.bar(x - width, carids, width, label='Carid')
rects2 = ax.bar(x, carname, width, label='Carname')
rects3 = ax.bar(x + width, models, width, label='model')

ax.set_ylabel('Count')
# ax.set_title('')
ax.set_xticks(x)
ax.set_xticklabels(labels)
ax.legend()

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Here the `carids`, `carname` and `models` are lists with the data that needs to be plotted. The labels are the `xtick labels` of the graph and you could adjust the width to place the bars appropriately.

The graph obtained is as follows:

[image]